# Retrieve data from Database, and use it as a vector - array. Doctrine. Symfony2

Tags: arrays, vector, doctrine, symfony

I have this array that I'm printing with this function in php: print_r($curriculos);

```
Array ( [0] => SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle Object 
( [id:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => 51 
[nombrecompleto:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => Bobo 
[direccion:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => Miami
[estado:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => Lauderdale
[ciudad:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => Key West 
[telefono:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => 3 
...
[1] => SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle Object 
( [id:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => 52 
[nombrecompleto:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => Hola
[direccion:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => Ricardo 
[estado:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => hola
[ciudad:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => Manare 
[telefono:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private] => 25 
...
```

What I want to do is to access this array in the controller of my application, of course i have $curriculos variable in the controller.

The thing is when I try to access data like this:

```
$curriculos[0]["id:SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle:private"];
```

it says Cannot use object of type SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle as array in C:\wamp\www\sym\src\SofLa\SoflaBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php.

I've been trying others solutions like accessing the data like this $curriculos->edad. But it says Trying to get property of non-object.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you have an array of objects, right? So it should be:

```
$curriculos[0]->edad;
```

**However**, entities in Doctrine2 should **NEVER** have public fields (proxies won't work), so you should add a method to encapsulate retrieval of the field, something along the lines of:

```
class SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle {
  private $edad;
  [...]
  public function setEdad ($edad) {
    $this->edad = $edad;
  }
  public function getEdad () {
    return $this->edad;
  }
  [..]
}

var_dump($curriculos[0]->getEdad());
```

*Sorry for mixing english and spanish... I don't know any spanish at all, so I don't know if you use any equivalents of get/set when writing programs.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the hints. :)
I have the getters and setters in the Curriculittle class, but when I try to acces like this

    $curriculos[0]->edad;

It says:

Cannot access private property SofLa\SoflaBundle\Entity\Curriculittle::$edad in C:\wamp\www\sym\src\SofLa\SoflaBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

:(

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work.. You can't access private properties from outside the class. Basic OOP. Instead, use the setters and getters... that's why they are there: i.e `$curriculos[0]->getEdad();` or whatever it is called.

Comment: I'm such a dumb, of course, you're right. Thank you buddy. You rock.